# Symfony Sonata admin - disable menu toggle button

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Is there a simple sonata configuration to disable the menu toggle button? ('Menu-hamburger' underlined with red in the image below.)

[image]

I took a quick look but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Do you mean the "menu-hamburger" button in the left upper corner positioned before "Dashboard"?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following directory in your symfony project, if it doesn't exist yet:

```
mkdir -p app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views
```

The option `-p` will create also the parent directories in the specified path.

Copy the following file to the newly created directory:

```
cp vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig \
app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/
```

The command should be written in one line. Because of its length I broke it down to two lines using the backslash `\`.

Now you can edit the copied file `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/standard_layout.html.twig`.

Find the following lines (I have them on the lines 115 to 120):

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>
```

Remove them, comment them out, do whatever you need, clear the cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

and refresh the page. Voilà!

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner approach would be to just overwrite the block you want to change like this:

`app/config/import/sonata_admin.yml`:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout: AppBundle::Admin/standard_layout.html.twig
```

`src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Admin/standard_layout.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block sonata_nav %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-left">
            {% block sonata_breadcrumb %}
                {{ parent() }}
            {% endblock sonata_breadcrumb %}
        </div>

        {% block sonata_top_nav_menu %}
            {{ parent() }}
        {% endblock %}
    </nav>
{% endblock sonata_nav %}
```